# Cannot start rails console unless spring is disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rails-spring

My rails development environment runs in Docker, and I cannot start the rails console without disabling spring using `DISABLE_SPRING=true`. The snipper below illustrates what happens:

```
app@docker:[project] $ bundle exec rails c
Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

app@docker:[project] $ DISABLE_SPRING=true bundle exec rails c
D, [2022-01-19T03:44:17.663136 #20] DEBUG -- sentry: initialized a background worker with 6 threads
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.4.4)
irb(main):001:0>
```

I've tried rebuilding my docker image from scratch, deleting the `Gemfile.lock` and building again. Nothing works, except for disabling spring.

Surprisingly, `rails server` works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem here after upgrading to spring 4.0. And the same solution with the env variable also works for me.